# Can irregular sleeping hours cause developmental issues for the brain?

Tags: neurology, sleep

It seems to be a common belief (i.e. [here](http://www.heartwiseministries.org/10-simple-steps-to-a-healthy-brain/)) that in order for our brain to rest and grow properly, we need to have regular, maintained sleeping regimes. While there seems to be no doubt that sleeping less than usual, or going to sleep on a very different time than usual can throw us off, I am wondering about what happens when you sleep good hours, but constantly shift your sleeping schedule. In particular, are there any permanent developmental issues that can be caused by a gradual, constant shift of sleeping times?

The question "[Can jet lag give you permanent memory and learning problems?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9984/can-jet-lag-give-you-permanent-memory-and-learning-problems)" partly discusses this, except that jet lag would usually involve big, irregular jumps in sleeping schedules, as opposed to say moving your sleeping time one hour forward every day.